# Интеграция Python в php-проект

Tags: php, python, интеграция

Всем привет, как передать данные из phpquery в python для обработки и затем полученную информацию вернуть в php?
Более развернуто:
Есть приложение-парсер для поиска по запросу(картинки, видео, текст). Оно добывает большое количество данных. Их нужно проанализировать с помощью нейронной сети в python и уже готовую информацию вернуть обратно, чтобы выложить на странице.

Пока вижу только такое решение: для запроса создавать директорию, куда складывать все данные и туда же вставить текстовый файл с описанием каждого файла, когда парсинг будет закончен - переименовывать каталог, например, xxx-END.
Под Python написать скрипт, который будет мониторить каталог с директориями запросов и когда будут появляться с -END на конце - запускать их в работу.
Передача обратно в PHP - по аналогии.

Вроде всё должно работать - на выхах проверю)))
Может есть вариант как быстрее сделать? Или какие-то стандартные средства коммуникации слонов и змей?

Спасибо!

Comment: Можно для запуска питоньих скриптов [system](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) использовать, или (чуть сложнее, но мощнее) [popen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php). (сами Большие данные вполне через файлы можно гонять)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно через [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/)

Оформляешь python скрипты как задачи для Celery. Потом эти задачи асинхронно вызываешь через [celery-php](https://github.com/gjedeer/celery-php)

Comment: Спустя полгода проб и ошибок и 3 года стабильной работы - подтверждаю. Это самое безгеморойное решение.

Answer (score 1):

недостаточно подробно развернута архитектура приложения.

- если это просто скрипт, то вызывайте любым удобным методом (popen, как предложили в комментариях)
- если это web-приложение (или планириуется) - зависит от нагрузки и архитектуры

  - если питон справляется по скорости и приложение не выпадет по таймауту и так будет долго  - все тот же popen
  - если не справляется - фоновый ajax/и тот же popen
  - превратить его в сервис с api, передавать команду на обработку данныъ и все тот же фоновый процесс.
  - сделать его независимым фоновым сервисом, который укладывает результаты, а фронт их отдельно забирает.

я бы остановился на двух последних вариантах, чтобы убить кучу зайцев - к апи приделать cli-интерфейс для дебагов и/или сервисных задач, подготовить к вебу и заодно подумать над масштабированием дальнейшем

Answer (score 1):

Если парсер - это скрипт, а не веб-приложение, то в него в конце можно добавить вызов python-скрипта через функцию exec (http://php.net/manual/ru/function.exec.php). Если питоновский скрипт возвращает текстовые результаты, то их можно получить с этой же функции. В другом случае считать по завершению команды exec, например с файла.